# Android WebView scale and size like Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, scale

What parameters of webview or webview.getSettings() do set for webview looks like Chrome?

My actual settings:

```
webView.setInitialScale(100);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Actual result:
[my app screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unxuq.png)
Expect result:
[expect result (Chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dSfK.png)

Comment: `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: This might be helpful for you.[webview example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441038/webview-is-not-behaving-like-chrome)

Comment: javascript...unfortunately, no.

Comment: I tried code below and it didn't work.  <br />
`webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) }Mobile/12F70");`

Answer (score 1):

```
private void initializeSettings() {
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/"+this.getPackageName()+"/databases/");
    webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    webView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.setFocusable(true);
    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

}
private void setChormeClient() {
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsPrompt(WebView view, String url, String message, String defaultValue, JsPromptResult result) {
            return handleAction(message, result);
        }

    });
}
```